# How to translate all particles relative to their object by the same offset?

Tags: particles, transforms, displacement

I have a number of particles either under or clipping through a (displacement mapped) plane, which is why I want to move them all up along the z-axis by the same amount (actually not the same amount, since the particles do not share the same z coordinate while I actually do want them all in the same xy-plane, but I guess that's another question). How can I achieve this, preferable without messing with the particle group meshes and their origin themselves? My setup for reference:

[image: Cigarettes on or below a tiled, displacement mapped floor]

[image]

Comment: Maybe adjust the emitter *Normal Velocity* parameter

Comment: That merely scales up the particles (and also the Hair Length property)

Comment: Please use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com) for blend files. Files on pasteall are removed in 5 months (or so) making the q / a less useful for anyone in the future.

Comment: Apologies! I tried Blend Exchange initially, but I thought it didn't work so I went for PasteAll. Turns out it only starts uploading after supplying a URL.